# How to delete a Price Object using Stripe API Call

Tags: stripes

I am trying to delete a product using API call but it throws an error saying
**"This product cannot be deleted because it has one or more user-created prices."**
I checked in stripe documentation but there is no API for deleting the Price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you do not delete product and price objects; instead, archive them by marking them as inactive. You can do this by setting active to false on the Price or Product if you don't want to use them again.

[image: set product.active to false]

Reference: https://pupuweb.com/solved-fix-stripe-payment-dev-error-delete-price/

Comment: Are you affiliated with the website references? Is it your blog?

Comment: what if i'm using a testing environment to create products and prices in batch and i want to delete them